# Create a new column with measuring the distance between rows x and y data with conditions

Tags: python, python-3.x

I have this dataset with a lot of rows and x and y coordinates of different `PlyrID` per Timestamp. I need to create a new column in my dataset with the distance of the row who has `InBallPos == 1` to the row who has `InBallPos == 0`. Note here is that per Timestamp, there are the same `PlyrID`.

I tried a lot of tutorials, read a lot about machine learning and python but couldnt make it work Please help!

Tried this so far without the distance measurement(this also did not work):

```
import pandas as pd

data = pd.read_csv('football.csv', index_col = 0)

f1 = data["IsPassOption"] == 1
f2 = data["IsPassOption"] == 0
f3 = data["InBallPos"] == 1
f4 = data["InBallPos"] == 0
f4 = data["InBallPos"] == 0
f5 = data["TeamID"] == 0
f6 = data["TeamID"] == 1

every_filter = f1+f2+f3+f4+f5+f6
data[every_filter].sort_values("Timestamp")
```

I expect a column with a distance metric like euclidian distance

Comment: Can you provide a couple of lines from `data` (or football.csv) so that we can see what your raw data looks like?

Comment: There are many timestamps with no InBallPos==1 at all, and there are many InBall==0 occurrences. I don't quite understand which pair or rows you wish to get the distance for. Can you give a very precise example from your data, provide 2 rows (preferably, here on SO) and the expected number you want, and in which row and into which columns you want this inserted into?

Comment: okay, You need to see it like: if the timestamp = equal than that is a moment on the pitch where all players (PlyrID) are recorded on a certain x and y coordinate. There is also a column with InBallPos which means if a player has the ball or not (1 has the ball, 0 no ball) and i need to know the distance from the players of the "defending team" (TeamID = 0) to the player who has the ball (TeamID = 1)
defending team players has InBallPos = 0

Comment: So you are interested in several distances (all pairs) for each timestamp? Basically, between the single player that has the ball, and all other players of the opposite team?

Comment: Indeed @Tacratis That is what i want :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I do not know of an automatic or more direct way to do this, but I checked a couple of cases, and this method seems to provide the correct answers. 
Please do not that you will have to sort the nulls, missing values, cases where there is noone with `InBall` of 1 and some other cases. For simplicity I defaulted everything to (0,0).

Also notice that you might be able to convert this to columns (if that is what you wanted) using a pivot table such as:

```
pivot = pd.pivot_table(data[['Timestamp','PlrID','X','Y']],index='Timestamp',columns='PlrID')
```

But I haven't continued past this point, because it doesn't seem to be what you wanted.

Anyway, I first generated a dictionary for timestamp:XY coordinates of the player holding the ball:

```
InBall_1 = data[data['InBallPos']==1][['Timestamp','X', 'Y','PlrID']]
player_with_ball=(InBall_1[['Timestamp','X','Y']].values)
player_with_ball={int(k):(a,b) for k,a,b in player_with_ball}
```

Then I used this dictionary and a couple of lambda functions to read line by line and get the distances:

```
data['distance'] = data.fillna(0).apply(lambda x: (
    player_with_ball.get(x['Timestamp'],(0,0)),x['X'],x['Y']),axis=1).map(
    lambda x: np.sqrt((x[0][0]-x[1])**2+(x[0][1]-x[2])**2))
```

Note the `fillna(0)` and the `,(0,0)` parts which take care of the default for `na` and the default for the dictionary lookup.
Note 2: I could have done all the work in the first `apply` function, but thought it would be easier to understand what is happening by splitting it into `apply` then `map` on that output.

I used numpy (`np`) but you can also use `math.sqrt` if you prefer, it shouldn't make a difference.

I'm sorry I couldn't find anything more elegant than this, and hope this still helps somewhat.

Please let me know if there are issues or if you need more help on this.

Comment: Tried your code but got a error that says:  KeyError: "['Timestamp'] not in index"

Comment: That is strange, you do have a column with that name. Maybe I read the file without an index, and that for some reason makes a difference? Try reloading the csv with no index, and make sure that the timestamp column is spelled correctly.

Comment: I did exactly what you described but still the error, very very weird. even copied Timestamp to make sure that there is no typo

Comment: Which line exactly gives you the error? (if it is the pivot table one, just skip it)

Comment: :) finally, we've been going back and forth for like a week.. Glad to be able to help.